# No sound out of headphone port on laptop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio

I cannot get sound out of the headphone port on a laptop. Headphones are plugged in, and sound comes out of the internal speakers. Windows behaves normally (sound switches to headphones when headphones are inserted).

It *did* work in Linux at one point, but something changed, we're just not sure what. Rebooting doesn't fix. This appears to occur whether or not PulseAudio is running.

Things I've tried:

- Rebooting. No effect.
- Booting into Windows. It works properly, so probably not a hardware issue.
- All of `alsamixer`. My only controls are this:

  - "Master" Volume bar & mutable, unmuted. Controls volume.
  - "PCM" Volume bar only. 100%.
  - "S/PDIF" Mutable only, currently muted, has no effect.
  - "S/PDIF" Default PCM", Mutable only, currently unmuted, has no effect.
- Killing PulseAudio. No effect. (It also won't stay dead! Something appears to be restarting it, and I can't tell what, but it is very annoying.)
- `alsactl init 0`, no effect.
- `sudo rm -f /var/lib/alsa/asound.state`, no effect.

**General system info:**

Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
Toshiba Satellite T135D-S1324

`lspci` says I have:

```
00:14.2 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
01:05.1 Audio device: ATI Technologies Inc RS780 Azalia controller
```

---

Some edits: Yes, the headphones are in all the way.

This works in Windows: You plug headphones in, the internal speakers stop making noise, and noise comes out the head phones. Windows says I only have two sound cards: the HDMI port (which I don't care about) and the "sound card", which it claims is a "Conexant Pebble High Definition SmartAudio" In Windows, both the internal speakers and the headphone jack show up as *one* soundcard, which in my experience, is typical. (This is a laptop)

Comment: Are the headphones in **all** the way? Sometimes if my headphones are *barely* out of the jack it will not play the sound.

Comment: Yes, the headphones are in all the way. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your kernel might not be detecting the card properly. Try setting the module options manually by adding the following line to your `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=asus enable_msi=0
```

([Credit Chris Benninger](http://www.benninger.ca/?p=60))

You can find a complete list of options [here](http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/sound/alsa/HD-Audio-Models.txt)

You might also want to have a look at the [Ubuntu HDA Intel Sound Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HdaIntelSoundHowto).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried installing the pulse audio volume control?

```
sudo apt-get install paprefs pavucontrol pavumeter
```

Also, In the "sound preferences" dialogue (click the speaker icon on the tray) does the hardware tab show your sound card? Do you see the device you're trying to use on the output tab? You may have to change the 'profile' setting to use the headphones instead of the speakers.

Comment: Thanks for the response to an old question (this is still as issue...). `paprefs` doesn't show anything useful, and `pavucontrol` doesn't seem to have any settings for switching between the speakers and the headphones. My understanding is that they show up as one soundcard, not as two. (I have another laptop, a Thinkpad, that does this.)

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution on [launchpad][1].
I'm not an Arch user so I'm not necessarily sure that you have this software but it's still a lead:

You install hdajackretask,
then select at the top the Realtek codec, 
in options you enable "unconnected pins",
Find and enable Pin 0x16 Override and select "Headphone"
  "apply now", and you restart the computer.

It would tell me that the device was busy, but it still worked after rebooting.

Some people needed to kill pulseaudio and prevent it from restarting to make it work [(see this link)][2] but all in all, it worked.

Hope it helps, bye!

Answer (score -1):

if it is about the bug #453395, then the solution is here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/453395/comments/5

> When you edit /etc/init.d/alsa-utils, and comment the 378th line:
>
> `# mute_and_zero_levels "$TARGET_CARD" || EXITSTATUS=1`